# c# load on-the-fly generated partial class assembly

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly, on-the-fly

I would like to override a virtual base class function on the fly and use this overriden method in application. If I write a basic example class:

```
partial Class myBase
{
   public myBase() {}
   public virtual void DoStuff()
   {
      throw new Exception("this function is not overriden");
   }
}

partial Class myDeriv : myBase
{
   public myDeriv() {}
}
```

And now I would like to override myDeriv.DoStuff on the fly.
So I create a string code block and compile it using

> CSharpCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource

method. After writing this dll to disk I tried to load it using

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("onTheFly.dll");
```

But application fails to find this overridden function. If you have any other better solutions I'm open to them also.. I just need to override functions on the fly..

Thank you all!

Comment: we need some more info: in which assemblies are these classes and we need to see the code where you override those classes

Comment: Not very sure if you can override virtual function on the fly. But may be you can use "new" keyword to "override" your NON virtual function ?

Comment: @hcb I have written the assembly which includes the base and derived class (I corrected example code these classes are partial). And I would like to create on the fly assembly or create, compile new overriding method and attach to this derived class.

Comment: @Tigran can I create a new function and/or override the old one?

Comment: that's what I mean, I'm not very sure if yuo can override at runtime virtual method, as virtual table content have to be rebuild, basically, but you can try to use "new" keyword.

Comment: @MCA Are you dynamically creating (and emitting and loading) a new subclass? And how are you attempting to execute the new code after loading it using `Assembly.LoadFrom(string)`?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible seems to be be caused by the same rule as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647385/is-it-possible-to-have-two-partial-classes-in-different-assemblies-represent-the) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132323/partial-classes-across-projects)

Quote from the original:

> "You cannot have two partial classes referring to the same class in two
>   different assemblies (projects). Once the assembly is compiled, the
>   meta-data is baked in, and your classes are no longer partial. Partial
>   classes allows you to split the definition of the same class into two
>   files."

or

> "You cannot use the partial keyword to split the code for a class
>   between projects. The partial keyword is a compiler trick; the
>   compiler will output one single class out of the parts it finds, so
>   all parts of the class must exist with the same binary file. Once the
>   class is compiled, there is no trace left of it being a partial class.
>
> If you want to extend an existing class you will either need to
>   inherit it (if it is not sealed), or create your own new class that
>   contains the classes that you wish to combine information from."