# Is it possible to declare a partial class in two projects

Tags: c#, .net, class, c#-4.0, partial-classes

Consider we create a partial class in **Project1** and we have a **Project2** that has reference to **Project1** .How is it possible to declare some other method of partial class in **Project2** ?

thanks

Comment: Do you want to create the partial class in Project2 with the same name you have given for partial class in Project1?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309939/should-you-use-a-partial-class-across-projects

Comment: possible duplicate of [Partial Classes across Projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132323/partial-classes-across-projects)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The partial construct is only a compiler functionality, to allow a class to be spread out in several source files. The compiled class still lives in one and only one class library (dll file).

There are two ways to extend a class in another library:

- Inheritance, unless the class is `sealed`. This requires that the calling code handles all object instantiation to instantiate the new derived class.
- Extension methods, which makes the code look like there are new methods on that class, but that is just syntactic sugar. It won't change the class itself.

Answer (score 12):

It is not possible to extend a partial class in another project. Partial is only compiler sugar. The compiler will create only one class in the resulting assembly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) that allow you to create additional methods for existing class

Answer (score 2):

Partial classes cannot exist out side assembly boundaries!