# Create partial class for referenced assembly

Tags: c#, partial-classes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to declare a partial class in two projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384084/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-partial-class-in-two-projects)

Say In my project solution, I have two project, ProjectA and ProjectB.
ProjectA created: MyClassA

Then ProjectB has ProjectA referenced.
Is it possible to create a partial class for ProjectA's MyClassA in ProjectB?

My Project A's MyClassA:

```
namespace TestPartial
{
    public class MyClassA
    {
        public string MyName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Project B's MyClassB:

```
namespace TestPartial
{
    public partial class MyClassA
    {
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    }

}
```

But obviously both properties doesn't merge.... So I guess is only work if they are in same project only?  Or there is some workaround for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, partial classes cannot span multiple project/assemblies.

From MSDN [Partial Class Definitions - Restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
:

> All partial-type definitions meant to be parts of the same type must
>   be defined in the same assembly and the same module (.exe or .dll
>   file). Partial definitions cannot span multiple modules.

Comment: To expand; partial classes are more an IDE feature than a runtime feature, telling the compiler that multiple source code files combine to make one actual class. That class still has to be in a single location in the binaries.

Comment: Bah, now make sense.  Oh well, now I have to restructure my project a little bit.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to create a partial class for ProjectA's MyClassA in ProjectB?

No. Partial classes are just a *language level* feature to combine multiple *source* files to create a single output class. It's not something the CLR is aware of, and you can't split a *class* between assemblies.

If you can give more information about what you're trying to achieve, we may be able to recommend alternatives. You might want to use composition, or *possibly* inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

No, a partial class must be fully defined within the same assembly (dll or exe). You can't have a partial class that spans two assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't according to Jon Skeet, which probably means it isn't.

See: [Should you use a partial class across projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309939/should-you-use-a-partial-class-across-projects)